# Is it possible to define a XML schema having a sequence of nodes, one for each enumeration value?

Tags: xsd

```
<xs:simpleType name="ItemCategoryEnum">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Kitchen"></xs:enumeration>
    <xs:enumeration value="Bathroom"></xs:enumeration>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Is it possible to define an element "Inventory" which should have as many
nodes, named "Category", as there are possible enum values for "ItemCategoryEnum"?

So, with the above example, compliant XML should look like:

```
<Inventory>
  <Category name="Kitchen">
    <Item></Item>
    <Item></Item>
    <Item></Item>
  </Category>
  <Category name="Bathroom">
    <Item></Item>
    <Item></Item>
    <Item></Item>
  </Category>
</Inventory>
```

Just specifying "name" attribute of "Category" as of type "ItemCategoryEnum" isn't enough
here because that only makes sure that "name" attribute can not have any other value than listed in enum. It won't complain if some of the enum values are never used. It means that following XML will also be compliant:

```
<Inventory>
  <Category name="Kitchen">
    <Item></Item>
    <Item></Item>
    <Item></Item>
  </Category>
</Inventory>
```

There is no category corresponding to "Bathroom" here. I want this fact to be caught as
an error.

-Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to promote the category names from being attribute values to being element names.

Failing that, you can use XSD 1.1 assertions to check the constraint (although you will be responsible for keeping the assertions in synch with the enumerated values of the type).